# Checking whether sentences in a database contain certain words from a dictionary

Tags: python, database, dictionary

I have a huge dictionary (in Python) containing millions of words and a score for each of them indicating popularity. (Note: I have it as a dictionary but I can easily word with it as a dataframe too). I also have a database/SQL table with a few hundred sentences, each sentence having an ID.

I want to see whether each sentence contains a popular word, that is, whether it contains a word with score below some number n. Is it inefficient to iterate through every sentence and each time check through every word to see if it is in the dictionary, and what score it has?

Is there any other more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach you can go with: '6' in my example code is the value of 'n' you have added in the question.

```
import re
words = {
    'dog': 5,
    'ant': 6,
    'elephant': 1
}
n = 6
sentences = ['an ant', 'a dog', 'an elephant']
# Get all the popular words
popular_words = [key for key, val in words.items() if int(val)<int(n)]
popular_words = "|".join(popular_words)

for sentence in sentences:
    # Check if sentence contains any of the popular word
    if re.search(rf"{popular_words}", sentence):
        print (sentence)
```

Comment: The code works, but with my data I'm getting "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'". I checked the type of the dictionary and it is indeed a dictionary. Can there be an error in these values, i.e. a value that is by mistake a string? EDIT: I iterated through the types of the values and wanted to print the possible strings, but nothing came out, so I assume the types are correct?

Comment: The possible reason for it can be either `val` is a `string` OR `n` is string. I have modified the above code so that you dont face that issue..

Comment: Thank you! I have just one extra question: I get: "error: unbalanced parenthesis at position ... " on the second to last line, which is probably because the list contains brackets and such. I tried regex.escape but it doesn't work, should I position the re.scape before the if clause? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Can you paste your code? along with the popular_words?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088182/unbalanced-parenthesis-error-when-working-with-lists-and-dictionaries-in-regex I posted it here since it is a completely different problem. Thank you!